# Problem with JEditor Pane while resizing the frame

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jeditorpane

i am new to java GUI programming. i am adding a JEditor pane (with HTML text ) inside a JScrollPane and added the scroll pane to a JFrame.The problem is when i re size the frame the JEditor pane vanishes.

Any one help me ?

Hi All ,

Following is the code :

here another problem is i set weightx and weighty for the pane .But still the JEditor pane is not resizing when the frame is maximized/mimized

public class GridBagWithJEditorPane extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
public GridBagWithJEditorPane() {
    initComponents();
}

private void initComponents() {
    java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

    Panel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    Button1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    Label = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    Panel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    ScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    EditorPane1 = new javax.swing.JEditorPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    Panel1.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    Button1.setText("Button");
    Panel1.add(Button1, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());

    Label.setText("Label");
    Panel1.add(Label, new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());

    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    getContentPane().add(Panel1, gridBagConstraints);

    Panel2.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

    ScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

    EditorPane1.setContentType("text/html");
    EditorPane1.setText("<html>\r\n  <head>\r\n\r\n  </head>\r\n  <body>\r\n    <p style=\"margin-top: 0\">\r\n      \rHere some html text sakdjslakdjsa dksa dsakjdklsajdklsad klsajd lksad<br>\n      asdka;slkd;laskd;sa dlksa dksa dksald;lsakd;lsakd;l ska;dl sal;dk;salkd<br>\n     asas;alks;laKSL;Kalk ALSKLAks;laSAsLAKS;Lk;slk<br>\t\n    alsdasldk;alskd;laskd;l sadksa;dlksa;ldk;saldk;alsd<br>\n    </p>\r\n  </body>\r\n</html>\r\n");
    EditorPane1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(15, 15));
    EditorPane1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(340, 220));
    ScrollPane.setViewportView(EditorPane1);

    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
    gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
    Panel2.add(ScrollPane, gridBagConstraints);

    gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
    gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
    gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    getContentPane().add(Panel2, gridBagConstraints);

    pack();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GridBagWithJEditorPane().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}


private javax.swing.JButton Button1;
private javax.swing.JEditorPane EditorPane1;
private javax.swing.JLabel Label;
private javax.swing.JPanel Panel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel Panel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane ScrollPane;
```

}

Comment: can you post some related code....difficult tohelp without that :)

Comment: sure i paste the code ..

Comment: hi Suraj .. i have added the code above ..

Comment: Cross posted at JavaRanch. Quit cross posting. Do you think we like wasting time answering a questions that has already been answered?

Comment: Hi Camickr ..ya i accept its in java ranch .. if i got the solution i will post here also and set the status of this question to "ANSWERED"..
anyway now onwards i avoid this kind of cross posting ..thnks to remain me ..

Comment: Yes, well the problem is that you've been away from your computer for 15 hours. During that time 3 different people could have been wasting time answering the question that you posted on another forum. So even if you do mark the question as answered in all forums its still too little too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem myself .
The solution is same as in

[resize problem with JList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720482/resize-problem-with-jlist)

Comment: I gave you the answer 5 hours before you apparently solved the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Small working example. Show us your code else we won't be able to tell where your problem lies

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Test {
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JScrollPane+JEditorPane");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(new JEditorPane()));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: ya it work .. bbut i am using gridbag layout ..i try to paste the code .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you set weightX/Y values for the scroll pane, but not the panel.

Why are you adding the scroll pane to a panel and then adding the panel to the frame? The panel is unnecessary.

Comment: hi camickr ... i have the constraint like that i need to add the scrollpane to a panel and then add it to a frame .. still i have problem ..how to resolve ?

Comment: I gave you the answer. In fact I gave you two suggestions. If you want a 3rd suggestion then listen to the advice you got earlier and you a more appropriate combination of layout managers. There is no need to nest GrigBagLayouts. Other layout managers are easier to use and understand.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not using `GridBagLayout`. There are plenty of more modern layout managers out there (`MiGLayout`, `FormLayout`, `SpringLayout`...), and for that matter you can almost always get what you want just by nesting `JPanels` with `BorderLayouts.` This will also make your layout problems much easier to diagnose.

Seriously, I've been programming in Java since 1995 and with Swing since 1998, and I've never bothered to learn `GridBagLayout` properly. It's just not worth the effort.

Comment: is the above layouts are custom one or they are present in jdk itself?

Comment: SpringLayout is in the JDK since Java 1.4.

Comment: (And BorderLayout has been in Swing forever.)