# resize problem with JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

i am having resizing problem with JList ...
Below is my code ...my requirement is to add a JList with some fixed size into a Panel and when i maximize/minimize the Frame the JList should increase/decrease accordingly .please help me ..how to achieve this?

Following is the design:

Hi Carl ,
It works in simple cases but not in the above case.
So i am explaning the above code now ..

i have a frame called "TestListControl" with GB layout.
        Add selectDevicesPanel with GB layout.
In selectDevicesPanel :
         Add selectNamesInnerPanel with GB layout
In selectNamesInnerPanel :
         Add selectNameAddPanel with GB layout
         Add selectTeamPanel with Flow layout
In selectNameAddPanel:
         chooseDeviceScrollPane
         clickToAddDeletePanel
         selectedNameScrollPane
In selectTeamPanel :
         selectTeamLabel
         selectTeamComboBox

```
public class TestListControl extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public TestListControl() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        java.awt.GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;

        selectDevicesPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        selectNamesInnerPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        selectNameAddPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        chooseDeviceScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        chooseNamesList = new javax.swing.JList();
        clickToAddDeletePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        clickToAddButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        clickToRemoveButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        selectedNameScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        selectedNamesList = new javax.swing.JList();
        selectNameLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        selectTeamPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        selectTeamLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        selectTeamComboBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        selectDevicesPanel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory
                .createTitledBorder("Member Selection"));
        selectDevicesPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        selectNamesInnerPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        selectNameAddPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        chooseNamesList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "XXXX", "YYYY", "ZZZZ" };

            public int getSize() {
                return strings.length;
            }

            public Object getElementAt(int i) {
                return strings[i];
            }
        });
        chooseNamesList.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(46, 88));
        chooseNamesList.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(94, 98));
        chooseDeviceScrollPane.setViewportView(chooseNamesList);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 12, 7, 0);
        selectNameAddPanel.add(chooseDeviceScrollPane, gridBagConstraints);

        clickToAddDeletePanel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridBagLayout());

        clickToAddButton.setText(">>");
        clickToAddDeletePanel.add(clickToAddButton,
                new java.awt.GridBagConstraints());

        clickToRemoveButton.setText("<<");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        clickToAddDeletePanel.add(clickToRemoveButton, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 5, 0, 5);
        selectNameAddPanel.add(clickToAddDeletePanel, gridBagConstraints);

        selectedNamesList.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
            String[] strings = { "XXXX", "YYYY" };

            public int getSize() {
                return strings.length;
            }

            public Object getElementAt(int i) {
                return strings[i];
            }
        });
        selectedNamesList.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(94, 98));
        selectedNameScrollPane.setViewportView(selectedNamesList);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 6, 0);
        selectNameAddPanel.add(selectedNameScrollPane, gridBagConstraints);

        selectNameLabel.setText("Select Name");
        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 1;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        gridBagConstraints.insets = new java.awt.Insets(0, 0, 8, 0);
        selectNameAddPanel.add(selectNameLabel, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.gridx = 0;
        gridBagConstraints.gridy = 2;
        gridBagConstraints.fill = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        gridBagConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        gridBagConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        selectNamesInnerPanel.add(selectNameAddPanel, gridBagConstraints);

        selectTeamLabel.setText("Select Team");
        selectTeamPanel.add(selectTeamLabel);

        selectTeamComboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(
                new String[] { "TEAM X", "TEAM Y", "TEAM Z" }));
        selectTeamComboBox
                .addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                        selectTeamComboBoxActionPerformed(evt);
                    }
                });
        selectTeamPanel.add(selectTeamComboBox);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        selectNamesInnerPanel.add(selectTeamPanel, gridBagConstraints);

        gridBagConstraints = new java.awt.GridBagConstraints();
        gridBagConstraints.anchor = java.awt.GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        selectDevicesPanel.add(selectNamesInnerPanel, gridBagConstraints);

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(
                getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(
                org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING).add(0, 400,
                Short.MAX_VALUE).add(
                layout.createParallelGroup(
                        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING).add(
                        layout.createSequentialGroup().add(0, 107,
                                Short.MAX_VALUE).add(selectDevicesPanel,
                                org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                185,
                                org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .add(0, 108, Short.MAX_VALUE))));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(
                org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING).add(0, 300,
                Short.MAX_VALUE).add(
                layout.createParallelGroup(
                        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING).add(
                        layout.createSequentialGroup().add(0, 39,
                                Short.MAX_VALUE).add(selectDevicesPanel,
                                org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                221,
                                org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .add(0, 40, Short.MAX_VALUE))));

        pack();
    }

    private void selectTeamComboBoxActionPerformed(
            java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TestListControl().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JScrollPane chooseDeviceScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JList chooseNamesList;
    private javax.swing.JButton clickToAddButton;
    private javax.swing.JPanel clickToAddDeletePanel;
    private javax.swing.JButton clickToRemoveButton;
    private javax.swing.JPanel selectDevicesPanel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel selectNameAddPanel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel selectNameLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel selectNamesInnerPanel;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox selectTeamComboBox;
    private javax.swing.JLabel selectTeamLabel;
    private javax.swing.JPanel selectTeamPanel;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane selectedNameScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JList selectedNamesList;

}
```

Comment: Which list?  chooseNamesList or selectedNamesList?

Comment: both the list box should be maximized/minimized when i maxi/minimize the frame

Comment: This GroupLayout thing doesn't make it easy to reproduce your problem. It would be considerate to reduce your test program to the small handful of components actually needed to look at the problem.

Comment: Why don't you read anwers in your other postings first. Maybe you will learn something there that you can apply here,

Comment: Hi camickr ..in the previous post also i didn't get the correct clue ..still that's pending things . i stuck with both the issues ..Camickr help me ..

Comment: But i accept both the issues are somewhat related ...

Comment: please anyone have solution for the above problem ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys i solved this problem myself .. thnks for ur co-ordination ..actually i did the mistake of giving weightx and weighty to the parent panel which is holding the both the Jlist and for the JEditor pane ... briefly we need to set weight parameters for all the parent containers which contains any component which you want to resize..

Comment: briefly we need to set weight parameters for all the parent containers which contains any component which you want to resize...... Which was exactly the suggeston I gave you 4 hours before you apparently solved the problem on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Your list won't get much bigger if you do this:

`chooseNamesList.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(46, 88));`

Comment: i set chooseNamesList.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(146, 188)); .but still i am getting this issue

Comment: Hi Carl .. do u have the solution for this problem?

Comment: As I mentioned, I had a problem duplicating your program thanks to the exotic GroupLayout classes. As it is, I'm happy you managed to find a solution on your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a prototype cell value, the JList will not resize when the data is changed.

See [The JList Javadoc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue%28java.lang.Object%29) for the setPrototypeCellValue(Object) method.